# what is the best way to store fixture for men doubles tournament

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am designing an sports app where I need to create fixture for doubles tournament like Men doubles event in Tennis and then store it for future usage. In doubles 2 players plays as a team against another team of 2 players. Fixture looks something like the attached image

[image: Doubles tournament Fixture]

For each match in the fixture I need to record score and then winner/runner up. For 2nd round onwards I need to know from which match winners player will come to the 2nd round match.

I have designed the database something like this. Kindly let me know if there could be better design.

```
create table doubles_fixture(
    doubles_fixture_id bigint(20) not null auto_increment primary key,
    fixture int not null,#fk fixture
    round varchar(32),
    match1 bigint(20),#fk doubles_match
    match2 bigint(20),#fk doubles_match
    player1 bigint(20), #fk ,
    player2 bigint(20),#fk
    player3 bigint(20),#fk
    player4 bigint(20),#fk
    game varchar(16) not null check (game IN ('badminton','cricket','tt','carrom','chess','tennis')),
    match_score varchar(128),
    winner1 bigint(20),
    winner2 bigint(20),
    winner1_points_gain float,
    winner2_points_gain float,
    losser1_points_lost float,
    losser2_points_lost float,
    match_start_time timestamp,
    match_end_time timestamp,
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk1 foreign key(fixture) references fixture(fixture_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk2 foreign key(match1) references singles_fixture(doubles_fixture_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk3 foreign key(match2) references singles_fixture(doubles_fixture_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk4 foreign key(player1) references oyetournament_user(user_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk5 foreign key(player2) references oyetournament_user(user_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk6 foreign key(winner) references oyetournament_user(user_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk7 foreign key(player3) references oyetournament_user(user_id),
    constraint doubles_fixture_fk8 foreign key(player4) references oyetournament_user(user_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Instead of storing all the game (type) and players data for each match, I'd store them on tournament level. That way there can't be wrong data (e.g. teams having wrong players in different matches). What are `round`, `fixture`, `match1` and `match2` are unclear to me. Instead of varchar in `match_score` I'd try to figure what kind of numbers should be used.

Comment: fixture is another table and which is for tournament. Each tournament has fixture.You can see the foreign key reference. Each fixture has many rounds like quarterfinal, semi final, final so round is for that. In the first round you can fix match between 2 teams (each containing 2 players) but in the 2nd round onwards match between 2 teams are decided based on the result of match in the previous round. Winner of each match will go to the next round and looser will be eliminated from the tournament.

Comment: So from 2nd round onwards to know from which match player will come, we have kept self key like match1 and match2. match_score will be something like this 21-11,13-21,21-18

Comment: Start by making a `Match` table.  That will pull most of the columns out of `Fixture`.  As a general rule, splaying an array across multiple columns is a bad schema design.  Fixture has a lot of such arrays, some with 4 columns; Match will have only a few, with 2 columns each